# Recommended JSP tag libraries

Tags: java, jsp

I'm looking for a collection of rich, well-written, stable, customizable and cool jsp 'controls'.

- JSF has richfaces, primefaces, icefaces
- GWT has ext-gwt, gwt-ext, advanced-gwt, on-gwt

Does something like this exist in JSP? Some tag library that has calendars, sortable and pageable tables, ajax autocompletes, pick-lists, partial requests, etc.

I know displaytag, ajax-tags and jspcontrols, but these aren't so complete as the ones listed above for the other display technologies.

If no such library exists, please advise which are the best libraries that cover parts of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please see this and possible then answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927998/in-struts1-3-from-jsp-page-to-action-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [SweetDEV RIA](http://sweetdev-ria.ideotechnologies.com/) (which is/was used by a french bank), it looks close to what you're looking for. See the [demo here](http://sweetdev-ria.ideotechnologies.com/sweetdev-ria-gettingStarted/).

Some other projects you might want to check (they don't cover all your needs though):

- [Rialto TagLib](http://rialto.improve-technologies.com/wiki/taglib)
- [Prize Tags](http://www.jenkov.com/prizetags/index.html)
- [jQuery UI Taglib](http://kenai.com/projects/jquery-ui-taglib)

#### See also:

- [Java Ajax Frameworks](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Java_Ajax_Frameworks)
- [Open Source JSP Tag Libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/jsp-tag-libraries)

Comment: Damn, the demo of forms components seems to be broken. Not nice for a demo :S

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, most features you listed (except partial requests and maybe pick-lists (what's that?)) rely mostly on javascript and not on back-end logic. I mean, calendar doesn't pull list of days out of database, it functions in the browser completely. Thus, it makes more sense to have them done in js.

I won't be too original recommending jquery for that, it has many fabulous plug-ins, and jquery-ui isn't bad either.

**edit**  I worked very little with both jsf and gwt, so can't tell how much power their offer and if it works better than js solutions.

Comment: You might well use a tag library to make the coupling between the JSP and JS code easier.

Comment: yes, this answer makes a lot of sense, but so does @Donal Fellows' comment. I would like to use as little javascript as possible, because it can be encapsulated in a taglib.

Comment: Yes, I understand why you would do that. Have you considered creating such library yourself? :)  Wrapping js call in jsp tag and passing configurable options shouldn't be much of a problem. But, from my experience, you can't get rid of javascript completely: it's still needed for custom event handlers and without them your application will be very limited. Sadly, you can't write them in java and pass to the browser.

Comment: With JSF and Richfaces I've got rid of JS almost completely (except for some little hacks) :) I shouldn't create a library myself if there is something already existing :)

Comment: I understand, it's just that I'm opposed to sending request back to server to reload whole element if all it takes is just toggling one little thing in DOM :)